# Istio gateway internal proxy

Tags: istio

I'm looking for an internal cluster proxy and on Istio's Gateway documentation i found the following:

> You can also use a gateway to configure a purely internal proxy

So my question is how i could do that? I assume that the specific implementation it's just a single envoy running on the cluster. For the Gateway's manifest, selector is required which most of the times it's the ingressgateway that handles traffic coming from outside the cluster. What should be the selector in my case, since i need the internal implementaition?

Answer (score 3):

You can use istio `mesh` gateway for that.

There is an example in istio [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/gateway/), take a look at the bold font.

> For example, the following VirtualService splits traffic for https://uk.bookinfo.com/reviews, https://eu.bookinfo.com/reviews, http://uk.bookinfo.com:9080/reviews, http://eu.bookinfo.com:9080/reviews into two versions (prod and qa) of an internal reviews service on port 9080. In addition, requests containing the cookie “user: dev-123” will be sent to special port 7777 in the qa version. **The same rule is also applicable inside the mesh for requests to the “reviews.prod.svc.cluster.local” service.** This rule is applicable across ports 443, 9080. Note that http://uk.bookinfo.com gets redirected to https://uk.bookinfo.com (i.e. 80 redirects to 443).

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: bookinfo-rule
  namespace: bookinfo-namespace
spec:
  hosts:
  - reviews.prod.svc.cluster.local
  - uk.bookinfo.com
  - eu.bookinfo.com
  gateways:
  - some-config-namespace/my-gateway
  - mesh # applies to all the sidecars in the mesh
  http:
  - match:
    - headers:
        cookie:
          exact: "user=dev-123"
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 7777
        host: reviews.qa.svc.cluster.local
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /reviews/
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 9080 # can be omitted if it's the only port for reviews
        host: reviews.prod.svc.cluster.local
      weight: 80
    - destination:
        host: reviews.qa.svc.cluster.local
      weight: 20
```

---

As it's not well described in documentation I have prepared two examples with nginx pods, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59309172/11977760) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59625648/11977760).